# For Intrinsic cap calculation what should be time interval for integration of current?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, capacitance, spice, sram

I am trying to get VDD cap of SRAM memory macro. I am ramping VDD by 50mv in a specific time interval and then integrating the I(VDD) for the same time interval.

For different time intervals like 50n, 2n, 2p 0.002p I am getting different values of cap.

So the question is How should I decide the time interval ??

Thanks

Comment: Is this in simulation, or using real physical measurements? 50nS is a very short time, 0.002pS ridiculously so. I'd be inclined to use much longer times, 10n, 20n, 50n, 100n, 200n, 500n, 1u, 2u, 5u, 10u ... you get the idea, up to mS or seconds, plot them, and see if they're asymptotic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can have any time interval to rampup supply. Buy current integration should not just be for the ramp up time interval. Rather it should be for extended period untill the current settle to steady state. Also do remove the leakage component from the total area under the curve